# Taking input and outputting one word per line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take a users input and parse the message to display each word of the message on a separate line. I researched it and looks like I would use as similar setup as the following

```
console.log("string text line 1\n\string text line 2");
```

but not sure how to implement my input of  into it and out of

```
<p id="op"></p>
```

or perhaps a div for output.

I have not been able to find a solid example of what I need to do. So the user enters a sentence and when I hit the process button, I need it to take each word in the input field and output it each word on separate line.

```
<header>
    <h1>Parse Test</h1>
</header>
<br>
<p>Please enter a short sentence:</p>
<input id="inp" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="pass()">Process</button>
<br>
<p id="iop"></p>
<br>
<script>

    function pass() {

        var lx = document.getElementById("inp").value;
        document.getElementById("iop").innerHTML = ("");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you tried for us to review and see how we can help.

Comment: Please do a research and try to solve your problem on your own first. Then post your code where you get stuck. StackOverflow is not a place for 'Hey!, I need this to be done, can you write the code for me'

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery you can grab the string and then split by spaces such as:

```
var message = "My message to split on spaces";
$('#your_div_id').html(message.split(' ').join("<br/>"));
```